# How to find the first root of a function with 1 variable?

Tags: roots, matlab, mathematica, transcendental-equations

I have a function with 1 variable x (positive number), I want to find the smallest root (the smallest x, where f(x)=0), I know that my root is bigger than 6.5. and I have graphed the function for value of x=6.5 to x=6.55
[function's graph for value of x=6.5 to x=6.55](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9UV7.png)
this is my function: (e is exponent)

```
f=(3.0*(6.7e-3*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))-6.7e-3*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-1.7e-3*((x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)-1.0)*(100.0*cos(1000*x)^2+1.5e3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)^2+(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)+0.018)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)+2.8))-0.042*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+6.7e-3*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+0.042*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2+1.7e-3*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+0.042*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))-1.7e-3*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2+1.3*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)^2-1.0*(0.02*((1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))-71.0*sin(1000*x)*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))+0.01*((x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2-1.0*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+32.0*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))+0.01*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(4.0*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+25.0*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2-1.0*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2)+0.01*((x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)-1.0)*(4.0*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-(25.0*cos(1000*x)^2+366.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+25.0*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+1.0*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2-(4.0*cos(1000*x)^2+58.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)))+0.01*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))*((cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))-1.0*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+200.0*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)-0.02*(x-8.0)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)*((x-8.0)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+2.8*sin(1000*x)*(x-8.0)*(11.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+71.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-4.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))))*(0.25*cos(1000*x)^2+3.7*sin(1000*x)^2-0.25*(x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)+0.062*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+0.01*(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+0.01*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)+0.062*(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)+0.25)+1.0)^3-27.0*(6.7e-3*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))-6.7e-3*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-1.7e-3*((x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)-1.0)*(100.0*cos(1000*x)^2+1.5e3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)^2+(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)+0.018)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)+2.8))-0.042*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+6.7e-3*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+0.042*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2+1.7e-3*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+0.042*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))-(5.0e-3*((1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))-71.0*sin(1000*x)*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))+2.5e-3*((x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2-1.0*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+32.0*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))+2.5e-3*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(4.0*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+25.0*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2-1.0*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2)+2.5e-3*((x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)-1.0)*(4.0*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-(25.0*cos(1000*x)^2+366.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+25.0*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+1.0*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2-(4.0*cos(1000*x)^2+58.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)))+2.5e-3*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))*((cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))-1.0*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+200.0*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)-5.0e-3*(x-8.0)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)*((x-8.0)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+2.8*sin(1000*x)*(x-8.0)*(11.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+71.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-4.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))))*(5.0e-3*((1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))-71.0*sin(1000*x)*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))-1.0*(0.25*cos(1000*x)^2+3.7*sin(1000*x)^2-0.25*(x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)+0.062*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+0.01*(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+0.01*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)+0.062*(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)+0.25)*(6.7e-3*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))-6.7e-3*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-1.7e-3*((x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)-1.0)*(100.0*cos(1000*x)^2+1.5e3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)^2+(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)+0.018)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)+2.8))-0.042*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+6.7e-3*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+0.042*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2+1.7e-3*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+0.042*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))-1.7e-3*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2+1.3*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)+2.5e-3*((x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2-1.0*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+32.0*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))+2.5e-3*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(4.0*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+25.0*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2-1.0*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2)+2.5e-3*((x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)-1.0)*(4.0*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-(25.0*cos(1000*x)^2+366.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+25.0*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+1.0*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2-(4.0*cos(1000*x)^2+58.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)))+2.5e-3*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))*((cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))-1.0*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+200.0*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)-5.0e-3*(x-8.0)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)*((x-8.0)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+2.8*sin(1000*x)*(x-8.0)*(11.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+71.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-4.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))))+(1.0*(5.0e-3*((1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))-71.0*sin(1000*x)*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))+2.5e-3*((x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2-1.0*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+32.0*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))+2.5e-3*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(4.0*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+25.0*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2-1.0*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2)+2.5e-3*((x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)-1.0)*(4.0*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-(25.0*cos(1000*x)^2+366.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+25.0*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+1.0*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2-(4.0*cos(1000*x)^2+58.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)))+2.5e-3*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))*((cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))-1.0*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+200.0*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)-5.0e-3*(x-8.0)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)*((x-8.0)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+2.8*sin(1000*x)*(x-8.0)*(11.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+71.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-4.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))))*(0.25*cos(1000*x)^2+3.7*sin(1000*x)^2-0.25*(x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)+0.062*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+0.01*(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+0.01*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)+0.062*(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)+0.25)-(6.7e-3*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))-6.7e-3*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-1.7e-3*((x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)-1.0)*(100.0*cos(1000*x)^2+1.5e3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)^2+(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)+0.018)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)+2.8))-0.042*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+6.7e-3*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+0.042*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2+1.7e-3*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+0.042*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))-1.7e-3*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2+1.3*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)^2)*(6.7e-3*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))-6.7e-3*(2.8*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)+18.0*sin(1000*x)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)-1.0e-3*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2-1.7e-3*((x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)-1.0)*(100.0*cos(1000*x)^2+1.5e3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)^2+(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)+0.018)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)+2.8))-0.042*(0.71*sin(1000*x)*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)+0.71*sin(1000*x)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)-1.0*cos(1000*x)*sin(1000*x))^2+6.7e-3*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)^2+0.042*(x-8.0)^2*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)^2+1.7e-3*(1.0e-6*sin(1000*x)^2+(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8))*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))+0.042*(cos(1000*x)^2+15.0*sin(1000*x)^2)*(1.0*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))-1.7e-3*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2+1.3*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)-(0.25*cos(1000*x)^2+3.7*sin(1000*x)^2-0.25*(x-8.0)*(4.0*x-32.0)+0.062*(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(0.71*cos(1000*x)-7.1e-4)+0.01*(0.018*cos(1000*x)+18.0)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+0.01*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8e-3*cos(1000*x)-2.8)+0.062*(0.71*cos(1000*x)+7.1e-4)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3)+0.25)^2-1.7e-3*(1.0e-3*sin(1000*x)^2+(18.0*cos(1000*x)-0.018)*(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)+0.71)+(7.1e-4*cos(1000*x)-0.71)*(2.8*cos(1000*x)+2.8e-3))^2+1.3*sin(1000*x)^2*(x-8.0)^2)^2
```

if you do it manually you will find out that the solution for this problem is 
[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/deLkQ.png)

But I need a more general solution as my goal is to find the first root of this function when you replace each (1000*x) in the function with (x*10^15)

Comment: That's the most grotesquely long equation for a function I've ever seen. If it comes from a certain problem, I'd suggest you explain its origin so we can deal with it more easily. If it's from some research you're doing, I implore you to use more approximations, since that expression would be grossly inefficient to compute. But if you're just posting an overly long equation for the fun of it, I can't say I get it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, there is no single algorithm to find the root of a function, and the algorithm needed will be context dependent. Algorithms used for finding the roots of functions are called [root finding algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm).

Label the root $\alpha$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous, we can find an interval for $\alpha$ by finding where $f(x)$ changes sign.

We could find the first $n\in\mathbb{N}$, for small enough $\Delta x$, such that $f(n\Delta x)<0$. This method isn't very efficient (less than the method of bisection) but it can give us an interval that contains $\alpha$. Also, if $f(x)$ oscillates rapidly, to the point where it's almost discontinuous, this method might be more appropriate. For $\Delta x=1$, the method tells us that $f(8)$ is the first $f(x)<0$. Hence, $\alpha\approx8$, or $\alpha\in(7,8)$. This doesn't actually prove that the lowest root is in this interval, it's just the lowest root we know of. This method is in the Python3 code below.

```
x=0
h=1        #partition width
bound=10        #highest value of x we'll check
while x<bound:
    if f(x)<0:
        print(x)
        x=bound
    else:
        x=x+h
```

A simple root finding algorithm is the method of bisection. This method splits the interval in half, depending on the sign of the function at the midpoint. If the original interval is $(a,b)$, the new interval is $(a,\frac{a+b}{2})$ if $f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)$ has the opposite sign to $f(a)$ or $(\frac{a+b}{2},b)$, if not. The Python3 code below tells us, for enough iterations, that $\alpha=7.207343999412696\pm10^{-15}$. You could do the same method with $\cos(x\cdot10^{15})$ in your function too but it would oscillate so quickly, it might be tricky to know if your root is really the first root.

```
a=7        #lower bound of interval
b=8        #upper bound
n=10        #number of iterations
i=0        #index of iterations
while i<n:
    if f((a+b)/2)<0:
        b=(a+b)/2
        print(a,b)
        i=i+1
    else:
        a=(a+b)/2
        print(a,b)
        i=i+1
```

There are other algorithms that can be used, but they depend on the degree of continuity and differentiability of the function in question. Your function oscillates fairly rapidly, so methods like the secant method or Newton-Raphson method might fail. The figure below shows a GNUPLOT graph of $f(x)$ over $(5,8)$.

[image]